# ArcGIS Administrator's "Availability" tab crashes the application

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

I'm seeing a strange problem in the ArcGIS Administrator for Desktop. The Availability tab is crashing the application, with an endless loop listing 3D Analyst (which doesn't appear to be fully enabled). Both 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst should be licensed.

ArcGIS Desktop functions normally, so the floating LM is working - but 3D and Spatial Analyst are listed as "not available". The application freezes and I need to force-close it.

I'm running Windows 7 on a Mac, using Parallels (not sure if that makes a difference). Interestingly this exact problem occurs on 2 Macs using the same setup.

Before I uninstall the LM, is there anything I should test or check?

[image]

Comment: So this just started happening out of nowhere? No upgrade, new installs, nothing that might trigger the weirdness?

Comment: TBH I think it's always done this - I haven't tried to use 3D Analyst for ages. As you can see the license is about to expire so I guess I'll re-install the LM once I get my new license file, and report back on whether it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from Esri Australia's tech support, and was to [clear the trusted storage](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-clear-or-delete-trusted-storage-for-concurrentus-000011660):

- Stop the License Manager service
- Navigate to the FLEXnet folder
- Remove the 'ArcGIS_xxxxxxxx_tsf.data' files within the FLEXNet folder
- Start the License Manager service